# Sending IDENTIFY DEVICE COMMAND - ATA PASS THROUGH on raid - SSD

Tags: windows, raid, deviceiocontrol, ata

My aim is to detect Solid State Drives in systems with raid configuration. Using smartmontools' following command I observe bit 434 (217) shows value 1 for SSD: smartctl -i -r ataioctl,2 /dev/csmi0,0

Attempting to read the same 512 bytes of data I am trying to send IDENTIFY DEVICE commands in following 2 ways:

Method 1 fails with DeviceIoControl() set GetLastError() as 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER), Can you help me in understanding what could be wrong and am I on the right track?

Method 2 has info->IoctlHeader.ReturnCode = 3 which means CSMI_SAS_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER.(CSMI buffer provided is too small)

///////// Method 1 /////////

```
handle = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0",
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    NULL,
                    NULL);
if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{ 
    printf("Unable to open handle to device , Error %u\n", GetLastError());         
    return 1;
}

//Allocate memory for ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX and clear the contents 
pATAData = (PATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX) VirtualAlloc(NULL, dataSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE); 
ZeroMemory(pATAData,dataSize); 
//Fill in the IDENTIFY DEVICE query data 
pATAData->Length = sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX); 
pATAData->DataBufferOffset = sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX); 
pATAData->DataTransferLength = 512; 
pATAData->AtaFlags = ATA_FLAGS_DATA_IN; 
pATAData->TimeOutValue = 10; //Seconds
pATAData->CurrentTaskFile[6] = 0xEC; /* send the command*/ 

status = DeviceIoControl( handle, 
                            IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH, 
                            pATAData, 
                            dataSize, /* input buffer and size */ 
                            pATAData, 
                            dataSize, /* output buffer and size */ 
                            &bytescopied, /* bytes copied to output buffer*/ 
                            NULL ); /* no overlapping */
```

//////// Method 2 //////////

```
BYTE    portNumber = 0;
_stprintf_s(DeviceName, (sizeof(char)*128),_T("\\\\.\\Scsi%u:"),portNumber);

// get a handle to the miniport driver
handle = CreateFile(DeviceName,
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    NULL,
                    NULL);
if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Unable to open handle to device , Error %u\n", GetLastError());           
    return;
}

CSMI_SAS_STP_PASSTHRU_BUFFER* info = (CSMI_SAS_STP_PASSTHRU_BUFFER *) calloc(1, sizeof(CSMI_SAS_STP_PASSTHRU_BUFFER));
info->IoctlHeader.HeaderLength = sizeof(IOCTL_HEADER);
info->IoctlHeader.Timeout = CSMI_SAS_TIMEOUT;
info->IoctlHeader.ControlCode = CC_CSMI_SAS_STP_PASSTHRU;
info->IoctlHeader.Length = sizeof(CSMI_SAS_STP_PASSTHRU_BUFFER) -    sizeof(IOCTL_HEADER);
info->IoctlHeader.ReturnCode = 0;
memcpy(&info->IoctlHeader.Signature, CSMI_SAS_SIGNATURE, sizeof(CSMI_SAS_SIGNATURE));


bSuccess = DeviceIoControl(handle, IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT, info, sizeof(CSMI_SAS_STP_PASSTHRU_BUFFER),   
                            info, sizeof(CSMI_SAS_STP_PASSTHRU_BUFFER),
                            &bytesReturned, NULL);
```